# Prestashop - Product admin : autocomplete is not called

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, prestashop

I added a custom field named product_type in Product admin. It works well, but now, I'm trying to add an autocomplete to this field.

Here is my code (in `\mysite\admin\themes\default\template\controllers\products\informations.tpl`)

```
<td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
    <input size="55" type="text" id="product_type" name="product_type" value="{$product->product_type|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" style="width: 130px; margin-right: 5px;" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#product_type').autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term, ajaxProductType: 1 },
                        success: function(data) { response(data); }
                    });
                },              
                minLength: 3,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</td>
```

When I write in the field, nothing happen. The autocomplete is not called. No error in console. However, when I put an `alert()` in the `document.ready` function, it shows. So, why my autocomplete doesn't work?

**Version :** *Prestashop 1.5.6*

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Sorry to ask you that but are you trying to write with more than 2 characters ? Because you specified `minLength: 3`. Anyway, did you try to reach *manually* your ajax page and see if it returns json data ? Really no error in your console ?

Comment: Yeah! I called my ajax manually and it returns data. I entered 4 characters for my test. I look in the console while I type something in the field and no ajax call occurs.

Comment: Try adding `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('error: ' + textStatus); }` under `success` and see if it goes into it

Comment: No, it doesn't go into it. However, when I `console.log($('#product_type'));` , the object is found.

Comment: Did you try using entire url for your ajax page ? Something like `http://www.example.com/path/to/ajax.php`. Maybe it is a path problem, i don't know if this is executed in same directory at run-time, depends on how you structured everything

Comment: The problem was that the form was loaded by ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The form was loaded by ajax.

So, I had to move the script in the file `\prestashop\js\admin-products.js` and put it inside the function `product_tabs['Informations']` (because my field is under the tab Informations). I also changed the autocomplete script as below.

```
product_tabs['Informations'] = new function(){
    //... 
    $('#product_type').autocomplete('ajax.php', {
        delay: 100,
        minChars: 1,
        autoFill: true,
        max:255,
        matchContains: true,
        mustMatch:true,
        scroll:false,
        cacheLength:0,
        extraParams: {
            ajaxProductType : 1
        }
    }).result(function(event, item){
        $(this).val(item);
    });
}
```